# Parte del tooltip se muestra fuera del tooltip

Tags: html, angularjs, tooltip

Tengo una tabla en html, tengo un `<td><span tooltip-placement="bottom" tooltip-html-unsafe="Prueba de un tooltip un poco largo"></span></td>`

Cuando se muestra el tooltip, la caja de tooltip llega como máximo hasta el final de la celda, mientras que el texto del tooltip sobresale un poco del tooltip.

Comment: Hola, tu pregunta ES CONFUSA, te recomiendo leer [Que tipo de preguntas debo evitar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) ¿Cómo quieres ayuda si no pones el código? No somos adivinos ni das mayor información. Recuerda leer [Como elaboro una buena pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Edita o elimina esta pregunta y reescríbela con la información necesaria.

Comment: Actualizado, quiero decir, que cuando me situo encima de la celda de la tabla, sale el tooltip, pero como el texto es largo la caja del tooltip solo llega hasta donde ocupa la celda, pero el texto del tooltip ocupa más entonces hay parte del texto que sale fuera del tooltip